# Compressing large file with 7z and unpacking with unzip

Tags: zip, 7zip, lzma

I am trying to compress a large file with 7z to achieve a good compression and unpack it with zip to send it to people who do not have 7zip installed.

7zip was selected as it achieves a good compression for text files and is easy to install. Performance analysis of different algorithms for text files can be found at 
https://www.maximumcompression.com/data/log.php

```
7z a -t7z -m0=LZMA -mmt=on -mx=9 -md=96m -mfb=256 zipfile.zip largefile.txt
unzip zipfile.zip
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Archive:  zipfile.zip
End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on the last disk(s) of this archive. 
note:  tourEventsCountry.zip may be a plain executable, not an archive
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of tourEventsCountry.zip or
```

Comment: What you really want is to effectively compress a file in ZIP format, right?

Comment: I am wanting to effectively compress a file so that it can be uncompressed by a standard zip program under windows and linux.

Comment: Dont you need to replace `-t7z ` by `-tzip`?

Comment: @meuh: This does not work: System error: E_INVALIDARG

Comment: Clearly, some of your other options are not compatible with zip. Remove them all and it should work, then review each one to see if it corresponds to something unzip can cope with.